# css background position X important

Tags: css, background-position

There are belive to set background-position X to 0 with flag !important and background position Y without !important?

For example:

background-position-x: 0 !important;
background-position-y: 10%;

Comment: why you want `!important`???

Comment: What are to trying to do.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: `background-position-x` and `background-position-y` will only support on IE and webkit browsers. Check this link for more info http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/background-position-x-y

Answer (score 0):

You may or may not use !important flag with background-position. It is a flag which force that value to rest of the page something like a constant.

```
<style>
.someClass{
background-position-x: 0 !important; background-position-y: 10%;
}
</style>
```

This will force background-position X to 0 for the page.